# Issue calling a string from another class - variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, jsf

i have a string in one class, that i would like to use in another, but i can not get it to compile

My code below, should pull the NewDestination from another java class, but i get the error variable NewDestination  might not have been initialized, when i try to run, how do i initialize it ?

```
@Named("Filter")

public class Filter{

    //public String NewDestination;

    private static final String FILE_TEXT_EXT = ".pdf";

        public static final String NewDestination;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Filter().listFile(NewDestination, FILE_TEXT_EXT);
    }

    public void listFile(String folder, String ext) {

        GenericExtFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(ext);

        File dir = new File(folder);

        if(dir.isDirectory()==false){
            System.out.println("Directory does not exists : " + NewDestination);
            return;
        }

        // list out all the file name and filter by the extension
        String[] list = dir.list(filter);

        if (list.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("no files end with : " + ext);
            return;
        }

        for (String file : list) {
            String temp = new StringBuffer(NewDestination).append(File.separator)
                    .append(file).toString();
            System.out.println("file : " + temp);
        }
    }

    // inner class, generic extension filter
    public class GenericExtFilter implements FilenameFilter {

        private String ext;

        public GenericExtFilter(String ext) {
            this.ext = ext;
        }

        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(ext));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second bean is anotated with SessionScoped and ViewScoped. Could a bean be in two scopes at the same time?

Comment: Your bean should definitely have only one scope.

Comment: Thanks that solved it, have expanded on the code now, getting a slightly different error

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final String NewDestination;
```

A `static final` variable represents an application-wide **constant** which has to be set during loading of the class.

Just initialize it directly

```
public static final String NewDestination = "some";
```

Or, don't make it a constant.

```
public static String NewDestination;
```

It all depends on the concrete functional requirement which is not clear from the question at all. The whole code looks strange, so it's also hard to make an educated guess based on the code provided so far.

Further should be noted that this all has nothing to do with JSF. It's just basic Java. You wasn't even able to compile the class, so that's completely beyond JSF. [Take some time to learn basic Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html). Constants are covered in [this chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). JSF has a quite steep learning curve. If you already don't know basic Java SE, let alone Servlet API, then the JSF learning journey would take longer at least twice and ain't going to be funny.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, what i was trying to do is search all the files in a folder for all the pdf files so i can display this to the user, if i am unable to use basic java to do this task, what other solution should i do to achieve this goal

Comment: Stop with your project. Throw that code away and clean your mind. First take time to learn basic Java using Java tutorials. Then take time to learn basic JSF using JSF tutorials. Then restart your project and apply the lessons learnt.